# Package titlesec adds spacing around \section even with \titlespacing all set to zero

Tags: spacing, sectioning, vertical-alignment, titlesec

My minimal example looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{230, 230, 230}

%\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
%\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{0mm}{0mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{snugshade*}
\section*{Abstract}
\end{snugshade*}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: 1]

However, if I uncomment the lines to add the `titlesec` package, the result looks like this

[image: 2]

Obviously, `\titlespacing{\section}{0mm}{0mm}{0mm}` is not enough (or even wrong?) to return to the previous spacing. What are the right commands to make `titlesec` do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`titlesec` doesn't add spacing. But it adds a strut so that every section has the same height and depth. Compare this here (without `titlesec`) with a second section with small content:

[image]

and this output from `titlesec`:

[image]

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you. So, it's a feature then? I guess there is no way to disable this in `titlesec` other than patching its commands?

Comment: No as far as I can see there is no switch. The \struts are quite fixed (and in various places. But why do want disable it? Imho backgrounds of different sizes would look odd.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `\strut`. Even if it's there to make all the `\section` same vertical size - it still adds space around the text. Why not take the smallest space which fits all text ("Abstract", as well as "...." in your example) which should return the result from the one without `titlesec`?

Comment: The `snugshade` box is in the background of the whole Abstract section - not only the section title but including the Abstract text content. So it's not about backgrounds of different sizes. I just noticed that there was vertical space between the beginning of the background box and the title "Abstract" which hasn't been there before I included `titlesec`.

Comment: A strut is an invisible rule with the height and depth of a line. And it doesn't make sense to ask my "why". I didn't write titlesec. The package author has decided to ensure in various places that the sizes of the objects are the same regardless of the content and if you don't like it you can either define your sectioning command without titlesec, or patch the commands or make a feature request.

Comment: Alright, thanks :-) Even if you're not the author of `titlesec`, you still seem to have a lot of experience with it. Certainly more than I have. So why shouldn't you know something about the "*why*" I asked? A reason a beginner like me maybe doesn't think of. That's why I asked. :-)

Comment: It's in the to do list. But I'm so busy with babel--